# Orchard CMS content preview not working properly with overrides

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I have created a theme and formatted my blog using view overrides in Orchard.  However, when I attempt to preview a blog post, the preview does not take into account these overrides.  I think this is due to the fact the preview URL does not match the layout overrides I've created based on URL's.

Actual URL: http://localhost:30321/blog/post-title
Preview URL: http://localhost:30321/Contents/Item/Preview/9460

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: I think there is almost no use case where you would want an override based on a url, but it is exactly doing what you'd expect: only matching the url it uses the override

Comment: I override based on url because I want my blog to have a different layout than the regular pages.  That is not a normal use case?  How else could I accomplish that?

Comment: You could use an override on your blog content type for example

Comment: Do you use the layout module for your layouts instead of creating layout overrides in the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use alternates, which you can read more about [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/)

Like one of the comments mentioned you shouldn't be doing view overrides (alternates) with urls unless you have a very good use case for it. You would be better off using the content type alternate. So if you had a content type called BlogPost, you could name your view file Content-BlogPost.cshtml. You should add these files to your theme project.

Comment: What do you do if you want to run different javascript on different pages?  Do you put the calls in the content overrides?

Comment: I can't picture what you are trying to do, can you explain in more detail? It sounds like you are talking about some type of javascript modularization. There are multiple ways you could do this though. I find the easiest way is to make unique files for each page/module/feature, and make sure it is wrapped in an anonymous function. Then make a global initialize function, and call that from view file. This makes sure only certain javascript executes on a certain page but would allow you to bundle everything into a single file if you wanted for optimizations.